# SCC compliant version control

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm new to version control and reading about some of the ones available out there. I noticed the term SCC-Compliant (used with clearcase), and the definition from wikipedia is:

> SCC compliant as applied to revision control software, means that a
>   program uses a particular interface defined by Microsoft for Visual
>   SourceSafe.[1] The SCC denotes Source Code Control

Is this concept of SCC-compliance huge or not that meaningful? Do most version control systems have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding ClearCase, as mentioned in this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21126483):

> The SCC API is an interface specification, defined by Microsoft® that defines hooks for a number of common source control operations.
>
> An application (typically an "integrated" development environment (IDE) of any kind) can provide source control functions without implementing the functions itself.
>
> If an SCC compliant code control system is installed, the application dispatches code control operations to the source control tool (e.g. Visual Studio > ClearCase).

That being said:

- if you are new to version control, try and stay away from ClearCase: it isn't the more practical one by far ;)
- [IBM Jazz](https://jazz.net/about/) protocol is a much more recent standard, that other SCM tools can use to integrate into other environments.

So while the concept of tool integration is important, the SCC concept is quite old, and limited to version control.
As opposed to Application Hub communication protocol, for integrating any two applications together, like Jazz.